# I cant't to access parent element when I'm using the BEM naming convention in sass

Tags: css, sass

I have the following styles and want to set `max-with` to parent element when it contains the circle children.

```
.mdc-layout-grid {
  min-width: $mobile-min-size;
  &__inner {
    .grid-circle-container {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      // set max-width of .mdc-layout-grid__inner in this block
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access parent element with css/scss/less etc. You have to find another approach, like adding a class with JS to the parent and style it with it.

Comment: @Rado https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector

Comment: @Rado It is possible in SASS with adding '&' at the end of the selector, but I have problem with BEM syntax

Comment: No you cannot style a parent element based on its children, as you want for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** style a `parent` selector based on a `children`. **However** Sass allows you to style the `parent` from *within* the `children`. Like so:

```
.mdc-layout-grid {
  min-width: $mobile-min-size;
  &__inner {
    .grid-circle-container {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      
      @at-root .mdc-layout-grid {
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which might be useful in certain use cases.

Hope I could help at least a little ;D

Comment: Thank you for your response but I need to change style of parent if it contains a specific child :) I think It's possible just with JS.

Comment: Yes, use the `:has()` sytanx

Comment: The `:has()` has browser compatibility issue! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: @pichlou, Oh, hahah, I see.